# Google Analytics causing Firefox to fail?

Tags: firefox, analytics

Ive noticed firefox has been failing on a lot of websites randomly.

I noticed while looking through the GA JS that there is a mention of Firefox but no mention of Chrome, Opera, IE etc

http://google-analytics.com/ga.js

Im wondering if any JS guru knows what the code is doing to the reference of firefox? and also whether this code could make ffox crash?

Cheers

K

Comment: If Google was making FF crash, there'd be a LOT of screaming out there.

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?  Can you link to some of your crash reports from about:crashes?

Comment: last crash was two months ago - ffox is just freezing, doing the same thing on wifes pc too - strange, reason why i mention ffox and ga is bz no other browser is mentioned in ga and i wanted to see if there is a reason why ffox is being managed separately

Answer (score 1):

Bringing up dead posts, but has started once more... 
Mi FF 15.0 (yes Beta), started to fail TODAY on Google  page, and was crashing on others since a couple of days ago.

I just simply add "google-analytics.com" to the hosts file to block it and ALL is well now.

guess that I'm staying away from google EXTRA data on my browsing habits from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing my extensions one by one, I found that it's the "**Https Everywhere**" extension that caused it. Its trying to call https versions of Google Analytics API.

To resolve this problem, I **unchecked** the "Google API" redirection rule in "**Https Everywhere options**".